# The definite article with the word "weather"

Tags: articles

Generally the word "weather" is used with "the", like:

> What is the weather there?

But, what if the speaker wants to be more specific about the kind of weather,  will he still  need to use the article? For example:

> I would greet the weather that is a few degrees warmer.

Or would it be better to omit "the", as in:

> I would greet weather that is a few degrees warmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nouns when used to talk about types of things rather than actual instances don't take articles.

So this ...

> I would greet weather that is a few degrees warmer.

is fine.

This ...

> I would greet the weather that is a few degrees warmer.

implies there is more than one "weather" and you've been talking about at least two "weathers" - the phrase "that is a few degrees warmer" further qualifies which "weather."

If you weren't doing something like comparing multiple locations' weather on a map, go with "I would greet weather ..."

Answer (score 1):

You would say it without the article:

> I'd prefer warmer weather.
>
> I'd prefer weather that's a little warmer.

If you're distinguishing one weather from another:

> The winter weather in Portland Oregon can be dreary, but the summer weather is fine.